# How to add gdb-server that executed before debug session start in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, gdbserver

I can launch gdb-server from the console via schroot for the desired bin file. Like this:

```
schroot -c ubuntu1404 -p -- gdbserver :8888 ./NetBeansProjects/ima_23_27/dist/Debug/ima_23_27
```

After that, in Netbeans I choose Attach Debugger ... (pop-up window at the debag button) and set the following settings:

```
Debugger: gdbserver
Target: remote localhost:8888
Project: ima_23_27
```

Then I click OK. Netbeans will connect to the gdb-server launched from the console and the project can be debugged. For convenience in the project, I can create a separate configuration to start the gdb-server, so I don't need to start the gdb-server each time from the console, like this:

```
schroot -c ubuntu1404 -p -- gdbserver :8888 ${PROJECT_DIR}/${CND_DISTDIR}/Debug/ima_23_27
```

I tried to add gdbserver to .gdbinit and Debug command and schroot is not working